# Dual Monitor : 1 VGA port + 1 HDMI port , Will it work?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I have a machine that has a VGA port as well as an HDMI port.
My Graphics card is Nvidia GeForce 9200.
I believe I can achieve an extended display by utilizing the hdmi port using a hdmi-vga cable.
But my tech support guy in office is insisting I will need a secondary video card.
Can sombody confirm whether what I am saying is correct or not?
I dont have any experience with extended displays and dont have access to a hdmi-vga cable currently.

Also will a vga splitter work ?

Comment: Why are you going to VGA? Does your monitor not support DVI?

Comment: Also looking up the 9200, I am only getting results for a mobile GPU, is this in a laptop? Would you please download [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and click the camera button on the top right corner and post the image here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no it doesn't spport DVI , its company machine so i dont have much say , also downloads is blocked at my place , will try to figure out a way to get the exact info. And its not a laptop

Comment: Can't you just borrow second monitor and try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on quick research, the 9200 should support two monitors for general use without difficulty.  It would be simple enough to try it before spending money on a second video card. 
HDMI to VGA cables or adapters are available for less than $10.

A splitter simply sends the same signal to two monitors.  Duplicating the same display on two screens doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: i know they are very cheap but its very tricky getting permission to bring hardware and accessories inside my workspace

Comment: Why are you asking how to do something that you can't get permission to do?

Comment: I can bring my own h/w to workplace, if I can show them that it works they can procure it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are two ports to use, and it shouldn't be a problem for the video card to have multiple monitors, there are some chipsets in motherboards that won't allow it.  I've had this happen to me, i'll be able to get the machine to see one monitor or the other, but not at the same time.  Make sure and check with the Desktop or Chipset manufacturer.